# c# Validation for login

Tags: asp.net

My script isnt checking the requirement can u help me out with this?
I'm trying to make it run the script before it run the onclick to check if login is right.

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
        function checkform() {
         var name = document.getElementsByTagName("UserName");
        var pw = document.getElementsByTagName("Password");
            if(name.charAt(0)!='s'){
            document.getElementById("divMessage").innerHTML = "Please insert an S infront";
                    return false;
            if(pw.length< 8 && pw.length>16){
             document.getElementById("divMessage").innerHTML = "Please key in a longer password";
                    return false;
                    }

        }else{
       return true;
        }
    </script>



 <asp:Button ID="btnLogin" class="button" runat="server" CommandName="Login" 
      OnClientClick ="return checkform()" onclick="btnLogin_Click"  text="Login" />
```

Comment: which version of .net are you using?

Answer (score 3):

You are trying to grab the controls based on tagNames. This way it could also return you a collection of controls as it says "document.get **Elements** ByTagName" Elements is plural. If your controls which you are trying to grab: UserName & Password are the actual ID in the Server controls use the following code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function checkform() {
     var name = document.getElementById("<%=UserName.ClientID %>");
    var pw = document.getElementById("<%=Password.ClientID %>");
        if(name.charAt(0)!='s'){
        document.getElementById("divMessage").innerHTML = "Please insert an S infront";
                return false;
        if(pw.length< 8 && pw.length>16){
         document.getElementById("divMessage").innerHTML = "Please key in a longer password";
                return false;
                }

    }else{
   return true;
    }
</script>


<asp:Button ID="btnLogin" class="button" runat="server" CommandName="Login" 
      OnClientClick ="return checkform()" onclick="btnLogin_Click"  text="Login" />
```

In the case of the UserName & Password are not server controls by which I mean an asp control but rather its run on the client, for example its not a `<asp:TextBox....`
BUT a `<input ...` (which runs on the client) you could specify its `id` tag with the value of **UserName** and **Password** for the other one, with one change replace:

```
var name = document.getElementsByTagName("UserName");
var pw = document.getElementsByTagName("Password");
```

With:

```
var name = document.getElementById("UserName");
var pw = document.getElementById("Password");
```

Alternatively if you are trying to get it based on tagNames then you have to go thru the returned collection and find out which one is the control you want. For example if there is only one control with that name it will be the only item in the collection starting at 0 and if you go higher like 1 its out of range.

Hope this has been helpful to you.

Comment: I tried debugged and it didnt even go to my script OnClientClick ="return checkform()" Why?

Comment: Buddy can you post your entire page please if you still havent figured it out, from the above I cannot see all your code and what you are doing. Aplogies in advance for not getting back to you earlier.

Answer (score 0):

When asp.net controls are rendered they have different id may be  following are generating error
        `var name = document.getElementsByTagName("UserName");
        var pw = document.getElementsByTagName("Password");`

Answer (score 0):

Set the `ClientIDMode` of the controls to Static.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.clientidmode.aspx

this way the client ids will be the same as the server ones.

Once you have done that, change your js script to use getElementById();

Hope it helps.